# Somar Campos input em Tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meu objetivo é exibir a soma dos Inputs na Coluna Total no input "Total do Pedido", onde deverá estar também somado o Acrescimo(será passado na forma decimal(%)) e o valor de desconto(será passado na forma decimal(%)).

Tentei seguir a logica do javascript apresentado usando addEventListener e parentElement mas não logrei exito.

Conto com o apoio dos senhores.

Segue Abaixo o javascript

```
window.onload = function () {

    var preco = document.getElementById('preco');
    var quant = document.getElementById('quant');
    var total = document.getElementById('total[]');
    var table = document.getElementById('tb_vendas');


    /**/
    function getMoney( str )
    {
            return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
    }
    function formatReal( int )
    {
            var tmp = int+'';
            tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
            if( tmp.length > 6 )
                    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

            return tmp;
    }
    /**/
    table.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      var quant = e.target.matches('[name="quant[]"]') && e.target;
      var tr = quant.parentElement;
      while (tr = tr.parentElement) {
        if (tr.matches('tr')) break;
      }
      var preco = tr.querySelector('[name="preco[]"]');
      var total = tr.querySelector('[name="total[]"]');
      total.value = formatReal(Number(preco.value) * Number(quant.value)*100);
    });
}
```

**Agora segue o Html**

```
<form action="salvar_venda.php" name="form_venda">
<label>Acrescimo(%):</label>
<input name="acrescimo" id="acrescimo" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Desconto(%):</label>
<input name="desconto" id="desconto" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<label>Total do Pedido(Soma dos totais da tabela+acrescimo(%)-desconto(%))</label>
<input name="desconto" id="desconto" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<table width="200" border="1" id="tb_vendas" name="tb_vendas">
  <tr>
    <td>PRODUTO</td>
    <td>VALOR</td>
    <td>QUANTIDADE</td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 01 </td>
    <td>
        123,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 02</td>
     <td>
        456,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 03</td>
     <td>
        356,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>produto 04</td>
     <td>
        322,00
        <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $lp["precodevenda"]; ?>' name="preco[]" id="preco" >
    </td>
    <td><input type="number"  class="form-control" name="quant[]" id="quant" onkeyup="ValidaValor(this, <?php echo $lp["quantidade"]; ?>);" min="1" max="<?php echo  $lp["quantidade"]; ?>"  step="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control calcular"   readonly="readonly"  name="total[]" id="total" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular isso podes fazer assim:

```js
var form = document.querySelector('[name="form_venda"]');
var acrescimo = form.querySelector('[name="acrescimo"]');
var desconto = form.querySelector('[name="desconto"]');
var subTotais = form.querySelectorAll('[name="total"]');

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < subTotais.length; i++) {
  total += Number(subTotais[i].value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.'));
}
alert(total);
```

E agora é só aplicar a percentagem de acrescimo e desconto, que podes ir buscar cada um com `Number(acrescimo.value)` por exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado !, mais uma vez.

Comment: Perdão pela demora em marcar a resposta da Pergunta. Fiquei sem acesso a internet por um tempo e também Desconhecia este procedimento aqui no StackOverflow pois ainda sou novato por aqui